# Grouping records by equal number of records in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Imagine we have a table with a single numeric column C1.

I would like to select max C1 from every 5 consecutive records (sorted by C1).

Example:

```
sorted C1: 1,3,4,8,9,10,11,13,16,18,21,34,66,67,68,80,82
```

C1 split into 5 record groups:

```
1,3,4,8,9 – 10,11,13,16,18 – 21,34,66,67,68 – 80,82
```

Final SQL result I'd like to achieve (max from every group):

```
9,18,68,82
```

Can it be done?

Comment: What do you mean by a "record"? A Row, a column, a value?  "Record" has no meaning in SQL. What is `C1`, a delimited value, a column with many rows, a row with lots of columns? Present your data so it's understandable. Use meaningful words to describe your data.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for your comment. My perception of SQL table is that I have a list of columns and rows. I instinctively identify records with rows, i.e. OLTP methodology not OLAP. 

That being said I do appreciate that nowadays "record" is an ambiguous term with all modern features like NoSQL stores or column-oriented databases. Your comment is spot on and it actually made me think about my presumptions in terms of understanding   of old-era terms or how ICT nomenclature has changed in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to enumerate the rows and then arithmetic to aggregate:

```
select max(c1)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by c1) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by ceiling( seqnum / 5.0 )
order by max(c1);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=966ac59bccf54c11b0461ece0ce18dbf) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Not sure if it works correctly. I just executed and I thought result (MAX from 5 records) will be in incremental order, but they are rather random.

Comment: Without an order by clause, the rows in the resultset have no defined order.

Comment: @Larnu . . . That is what `ceiling()` handles.

Comment: @KarolKolenda . . . The order of the result set is arbitrary unless there is an `order by`.  I'll let you ponder on why it works.

Comment: @Larnu . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  It produces the results that the OP specifies.

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff, sorry to be so daft. It works perfectly.
PS: Extra thanks for db fiddle example. I've used JS Fiddle for years, but honestly have no clue that there is such a great site as db fiddle.